# How to save only numeric numbers from string into an array of int in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

in my POST variable i have: `print_r($_POST["partecipanti"]);`
It displays
["1", "2"]

I want to save only the numbers of the post variable in an int array. I tried

```
$array = array();
 preg_match_all('/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?+/', $_POST["partecipanti"], $array);
```

But print_r($array) returns

```
Array (
 [0] => Array (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        )
    )
```

How can i have a variable like

```
Array (
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
     )
```

Hope i explained good, thanks all in advance

Comment: There is no difference between a string with only number and an integer in php. But if you must, you can use intval() to convert to integer.

Comment: @Andreas of course yes there is a difference between numeric string and integer in php. Try `is_int("1")` it returns `false`.

Comment: `print_r($array[0])` And I suppose `$_POST["partecipanti"]` is a json string and can be decoded.

Comment: @WizardNx not sure what you are trying to say. $_POST is always in string format. Using is_int() on a obvious string is quite meaningless.

Comment: @Andreas it's actually meaningless yes, but you were saying "there is no difference between a string with only number and an integer in php" which is wrong or like I would like to say: "as true as is_int("1")".

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all` returns a new multidimensional array every time. But you could just "pop" the array:

```
$array = array();
preg_match_all('/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?+/', $_POST["partecipanti"], $array);
$array = $array[0];
```

Returns:

```
Array (
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
)
```

Comment: Note that there is no need to declare `$array` before the `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 0):

to filter integer values from an array, use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$arr = array_filter($_POST["participanti"], function($v) { return is_int($v); });
```

In case you want to convert the array values into integers:

```
$arr = array_map(function($v) { return (int)$v; }, $_POST["participanti"]);
```

In both cases the $arr contains only integer values.

Comment: i'm sure he was asking for a way to get only integer values from the array. not convert the array values into integers. it's filtering not converting, converting would need a different approach.

Comment: edited the answer to cover filtering as well as converting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$_POST["partecipanti"])` is a string because you use it directly in your example and the second parameter of [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is a string.

`preg_match_all` returns an array where the matches are in the first entry and contains array of strings. You could get that array by using `$array[0]` .

Besides `1` and `2`, your regex [`-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?+`](https://regex101.com/r/m9SJBJ/1) also matches for example `-8.44` or `99999999999999999999999999`.

If you want an array of int, you could use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with for example the function [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) for the callback.

**Note** the maximum size of an [int](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) and the rounding of the values.

For example:

```
$str = "test 1, test 2, test 2.3 and -8.44 plus 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999";
preg_match_all('/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?/', $str, $array);
$array = array_map/**/("intval", $array[0]);
var_dump($array);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/VMX05)

That results in:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  int(-8)
  [4]=>
  int(9223372036854775807)
}
```